# Has anyone ever created A VR UML Class model using A-Frame

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

I'm looking to auto-generate a UML class model in virtual reality using A-Frame.io (or another technology) by passing in values. Has anyone ever done something similar in the past? Not sure where to start.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [plantuml](http://plantuml.com/) which is a nice UML generator. Most of it's diagrams are generated as input to [graphviz's dot](http://www.graphviz.org/About.php). Dot is a layout engine - it takes a list of nodes and connections and puts them into 2D space and then renders them to one of it's output formats - or just returns the graph, but this time with coordinates on where to draw what. You could meddle with this data and render the elements with volume but on a 2D plane with dot generated coordinates. Perhaps even you could modify it to place them in 3D space instead of a plane.

Or you could just render the plantuml output on a 2D plane, place it in 3D space and it would probably be good enough. There are even [online generators](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000) for plantuml.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof - I'll definitely look into this!